# fltk attach image to window from a button

Tags: c++, fltk

So my question is: I'm trying to make a "carousel" of images (select image from file, load it and display it using "next_button" or load the previous one using "previous_button"). My problem is that i have no clue how to access the same window, I have defined at main, so I can attach the selected picture.
I tried passing my_Window& win but I get an error at cb_next saying that I cannot use this type (struct)
Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much for your valuable time!
Here is a sample of the code:

```
struct my_Window : Graph_lib :: Window
{
    //Defined buttons
    //...
    //Example of how I create and call the next_button(to display the next picture)
    static void cb_next(Address, Address); // callback for next_button
    void next(); 
};

//Here is what I use to make the button work
void my_Window::cb_next(Address, Address pw)
{
    reference_to<my_Window>(pw).next(); //cannot pass my_Window
}
void my_Window::next()
{
    //Load the next picture!
    //This is where I want to attach the image
    //but when I use attach(image) it doesn't know where to attach ( as expected)
    redraw();
}
int main()
{
    my_Window win(Point(100,100),800,600,"Images");  //I want this "win" to be accessed by the next button so I can attach the new picture.
    return gui_main();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's more of a C++ question.
Why is cb_next() a static method?
If you make it a normal method, you can access the same struct/window you defined in main using the `this` pointer. Writing `this` is also optional, you already call `redraw` in the next() method, which is actually `this->redraw();`.

Comment: Thank you very much! But because I'm new with c++ can u give me an example? So basically if I change it to non static I can pass the structure?

Comment: If I change it to a non static method then the declaration/definitions I have for the buttons do not work, because they expect a static value:

Comment: If you remove the static, you don't need to pass the struct, you already get access to `this`.